# How to modify channel of Discord webhook with Python

Tags: python, discord, webhooks

I have a Python script which sends messages using webhook assigned to my Discord server. I would like to make my program able to change webhook's channel sometimes.

On [Discord Developer Portal](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook) I read there are two ways of modifying webhooks using requests (1. [Modify webhook](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#modify-webhook), 2. [Modify webhook with token](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#modify-webhook-with-token)).

I have tested the easier second one but it allows only to change avatars and usernames:

```
 r = requests.patch("https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/.../...", json={ "name":"New Name" })
 # status code 200
```

Changing webhook channels are offered by the first one but it requires something called `MANAGE_WEBHOOKS` permission so the method below of course does not work:

```
 r = requests.patch("https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/...", json={ "channel_id":12345 })
 # status code 401 (unauthorized)
```

I have created Discord application and started reading about dealing with authorization for webhooks [over here](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#webhooks) but I stuck and I don't understand how to actually make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a fresh look at the Discord documentation I finally solved my problem. Below I write how to achieve such result in simple Python script:

1. Open Discord Developer portal, create new app, add bot and URI for redirection in OAuth2 section.
2. Create authorization URL using generator in OAuth2 section. For **Scopes** select `bot` and `discord.incoming`. For **Bot Permissions** select `Manage Webhooks`. You will get something like that:

   ```
   https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<MY_CLIENT_ID>&permissions=536870912&redirect_uri=<MY_URI>&response_type=code&scope=bot%20webhook.incoming
   ```
3. Open this link in your browser to connect the bot and webhook to your server. On acceptance, you will be redirected to your URI address.
4. The address will contain the `code` querystring parameter. I just copied this `code` manually and pasted it to the script in the following step (note that the `code` is valid for a short time so if you do everything too slow the authentication may not be succeed).
5. Here is the code which make necessary authentication:

   ```
   import requests

   CLIENT_ID = # Your client id 
   CLIENT_SECRET = # Your client secret
   REDIRECT_URI = # Your redirect URI
   CODE = # Your code from step 4.

   data = {
       'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
       'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
       'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
       'code': CODE,
       'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
       'scope': 'bot webhook.incoming',
       'permissions': "536870912",
   }
   headers = {
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   }
   r = requests.post('https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token', data=data, headers=headers)
   r.raise_for_status()
   ```

   The authentication is success if no exceptions are thrown.
6. If everything works well, run this code to change current webhook channel:

   ```
   ...

   BOT_TOKEN = # Your bot's token
   WEBHOOK_ID = # Your webhook's id

   json = { "channel_id": 12345 } # Replace with new webhook's channel id
   headers = { "Authorization": "Bot " + BOT_TOKEN }

   r = requests.patch('https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/' + WEBHOOK_ID, json=json, headers=headers)
   ```